# Convert an array of string to an array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Sorry if it's obvious for you guys, but here what i'm tryiny to do:

I have the following array :

```
$myArray=Array ( "024848772" ,"0550244954", "0560084252","0559180203","0673466366","021648334" ....);
```

And I want to have it like this :

```
Array ( array("024848772"),array("0550244954"),array("0560084252"),array("0559180203"),array("0673466366"),array("021648334") ....);
```

Comment: `$newArray = array_map(function($item){ return [$item];}, $myArray);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5);
function fun($v) {
    return array($v);
}
print_r(array_map("fun",$a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and add the result to an accumulator wrapping them in an array:

```
$acc = array();
foreach($myArray as $someString){
  $acc[] = array($someString);
}

var_dump($acc);
```

Example in sandbox [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f189dfcc983ff3cd6c7fef2e81a8873bd58cfd44).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$myArray=Array ( "024848772" ,"0550244954", "0560084252","0559180203","0673466366","021648334" );
$arrays = array();
foreach ($myArray as $x)
    $arrays[] = array($x);
//print_r($arrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really seeing the problem. Your original syntax works.

> $myArray = Array ( array("024848772"),array("0550244954"),array("0560084252"),array("0559180203"),array("0673466366"),array("021648334"));
>
> var_dump($myArray);